# Prison planet or dimension, inmates acquired green skin or eyes

Tags: story-identification

I read a novella many years ago where humanity exiled all criminals to a special planet, from which escape was thought to be impossible.

This strategy was highly successful, and there was no crime anymore in the civilised galaxy. Also, hardly anyone were exiled anymore. The outside world is portrayed as naive, unsophisticated, and not able to cope with harshness or guile.

Unfortunately, a problem arose, like an outside threat, and the help of the prisoners on the planet was needed, because they would be able to commit violence, or be able to lie their way out of the threat, or something like that.

These prisoners had created a completely new society, in which the smartest, most conniving, and deadliest of the lot rose to the top. The environment of the planet also gave them a greenish skin, or green flecks in their eyes, I can't remember which.

The only way to get help from the prisoners was to physically send an envoy to negotiate terms, which is where the story starts.

I can't give more details in case I spoil the story for others.

I'd like to read it again, but I can't remember the title. I've been searching for years, including on this site, but this is the first time I've asked for some help.

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: What does "many" years ago mean? 50 years ago? More? Don't worry about spoilers, story identification questions are supposed to contain spoilers.

Comment: Not sure about the green, but everything else sounds like Frank Herbert's *The Dosadi Experiment*.

Comment: I believe you can put spoiler tags on anything you want hidden by typing >> before it. That way we can get as much information on the book as possible :)

Comment: Spoiler tags are `>!`.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I never use tags :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. Many years means 20-30 years ago for me. I'll post more details and try to use the spoiler tags in a comment like this one. Hope it works. After reading the plot on Wikipedia, I don't think it was The Dosadi Experiment, but I'll double check it soon.

Comment: UPDATE: I got the book from Amazon, and I've read enough to know you were right, @DanielRoseman  Thanks so much!

Comment: Was this by any chance a *history* book about Australia? ;P

Comment: @DanielRoseman since OP confirmed that it was indeed _The Dosadi Experiment_, could you turn that into a full-fledged answer so that this question gets out of the "unanswered" ones? :)